# Gitlab Runner artifacts-downloader returns Forbidden when downloading artifacts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I have a pipeline with 3 jobs. The 2nd job would build docker file and upload.

[image]

But the 3rd stage failed with this error.

```
ERROR: Downloading artifacts from coordinator... error  error=unexpected EOF
```

So I tried to use `gitlab-runner artifacts-downloader` to download artifacts on the runner machine.

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner artifacts-downloader --url https://gitlab.com/ --token xxx-xxxx --id 359820234

Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=24718 revision=05161b14 
version=12.4.1
ERROR: Downloading artifacts from coordinator... forbidden  id=359820234 responseStatus=403 Forbidden status=403 Forbidden token=xxx-xxxx
FATAL: permission denied
```

However, I got the `forbidden` error. Did I miss anything?